Proof of a general version of Jensen's formula
I was reading the proof of Jensen's formula from the Noguchi-Winkelmann book (see photo below). They give a more general version of Jensen's formula that works for functions $\varphi\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$  of class $C^2$. It seems that it is just a clever application of the Stokes theorem. Unfortunately, an important part of the proof is  sketched and I don't understand it.
I can follow all the chain of equalities when $\varphi$ is of class $C^2$, but I really don't get the final part when they assume logarithmic singularities and they start taking small circles of radius $\varepsilon$ around them. In particular, it is quite obscure how they get respectively $O(\varepsilon|\log\varepsilon|)$ and $\lambda_v+O(\varepsilon)$.
For instance it seems that a certain point one needs to calculate the integral
$$
\int_{\Delta(\epsilon)}d\log|z+a_\nu|\wedge d^c\log|z|
$$
but it is not clear to me how to compute it.



Write $\phi(z)= S(z)+ \psi(z)$ where $S(z)=\sum_k \lambda_k ln|z-a_k|$ is the singular part and $\psi$ is smooth. Since you already understand how to deal with the smooth part, we focus on evaluating  the integral of the singular part. And by linearity of integration it suffices to handle one singular term at a time.
Thus  below we assume $S(z)= ln|z-a|$.  We wish to compute the angular average of this expression on concentric circles of various radii. Call that angular average $I(R)$.
Preliminaries. The intuitive explanation for the contribution from the logarithmic term is that the Laplacian of $h_a(z)=\ln|z-a|$ is a point-mass $\delta$ function concentrated at $z=a$. Thus if $a$ lies outside a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin, this logarithmic expression is harmonic in that disk, and satisfies the mean value property: its angular average over that circle equals its value at the origin, namely $\ln |a|$. (This proves half of the Proposition below). With more work , we can obtain a similar formula for the angular average in the case that $a$ lies inside that circle.
Proposition. $I(R)=\int_{|z|=R} S(z) d\theta = 2\pi \ln R$ if $|a|<R$, and  $I(R)=2\pi \ln |a|$ if $|a|>R$.
Comment. Identity  (1.1.7) follows from the Proposition by first differentiating the step-wise defined function $I(R)$ in $R$ and then integrating back in $R$. (We get a  point-jump contribution from the  derivative when $R$ crosses $a$.)
Proof of Proposition.
We'll use this  fact about the linear-fractional analytic self-maps of the unit disk: for each point $b$ inside the unit circle the  map $w\to \mu_b(w)=\frac{w-b}{1- \overline b w}$ maps the unit circle onto itself (and the interior of the unit disk to its interior). Thus when $|w|=1$, $|\mu_b(w)| =1$ and $\ln |\mu_b(w)|=0$ .
Suppose   that $a$ is inside the circle of radius $R$.
Then for each such radius $R$, $\int_ {|z|=R} S(z)   d\theta$ can be evaluated by
first re-parametrizing that integral by setting $z=Rw$ where $|w|=1$.
Let $b=a/R$. It lies inside the unit circle.
Note that $S(z)= \ln |Rw-a|= \ln |R(w-a/R)| =\ln R+ \ln|w-b)|$.
Thus $$\int_{|z|=R} S(z) d\theta= 2\pi \ln R + \int_{|w|=1}\ln|w-b)|d\theta$$
But $$ \ln |w-b| =\ln |\frac{w-b}{1- \overline b w}| +\ln |1- \overline b w| $$ $$= \ln |\mu_b(w)| +\ln |1- \overline b w| $$ $$=\ln |1- \overline b w|$$ since $\ln|\mu_b(w)| =\ln|1|=0$ when $|w|=1$.
Note  that  $\ln |1- \overline b w|$ is harmonic except at the pole point $w=1/\overline b$ which lies outside the unit circle.
The  angular average of this harmonic function equals its value at the origin, which is $\ln(1)=0$.
Postscript. A somewhat shorter explanation. If $S(z)=\sum_k \lambda_k \ln|z-a_k|$ then each term is harmonic except on the circles defined by $R_k= |a_k|$. When we take the angular average of each term, we create a rotationally symmetric  function that is harmonic in the variable $R$, true for all $R\ne R_k$.
Adopting log-polar coordinates $\ln R= u, \theta=v$ we see that in this new system of coordinates the Euclidean Laplacian is a multiple of $\partial^2_{uu}+ \partial^2_{vv}$.  Because $S(R)$ is radial and harmonic, this tells us that it is independent of $v$ and when regarded as a function of $u$ it satisfies $S_{uu}=0$. Thus $S$ must be a piece-wise affine function of $u=\ln R$. The last detail to check is that this affine function is continuous in $u$ and the jump in slope as you cross $R=|a_k|$ is exactly $\lambda_k$. Alas to check that I think you still need to appeal to the lengthy Proposition above.

This seems to be an alternative proof, but not what the authors suggest. Anyway it is fine, thanks
